# iOS converting UIView to ScrollView without destroying layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

Is there any possibility to move from UIView to UIScrollView without destroying all the constraints and placement. The thing is I build the whole UI without testing it on iPhone 4 and now I see some views should be in Scroll View to work. I tried few tricks but nothing works. Constraints gets deleted. Below is the example picture of sample:

[image]

Now I want that test1 UIView to be Scroll View, I tried to put Scroll View inside test1 View and then recursively copy test1 inside scroll view and delete old elements but it didnt work (shown bellow)

[image]

If there is any way to convert UIView to UIScrollView without destroying constraints (even programatically) that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried right click the view, go to editor and embed in scrollView?

Comment: I cant embed test1 in scroll view since it is root view. Good idea though. Is there trick to do that with root view?

Comment: Try copy and paste. Create a new controller, and add a scroll view to it's main view. Paste the view you copied from your other controller into the scroll view. Since you're making a copy, if it doesn't work, you'll still have the original.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

Simply replace the `<view>` element by `<scrollView>` in your XIB file:

1. Make a backup copy of your XIB file.
2. Edit your XIB file as plain text:

   - Xcode > Right click on XIB > Open As > Source Code
   - Finder > Right click on XIB > Open With > TextEdit
3. Replace the specific `<view>` tag by `<scrollView>`.
4. Replace attributes (see example below).
5. Keep the original `id` attribute.
6. Replace the closing `</view>` tag by `</scrollView>`.

I choose my battles. I prefer constraints as code.

---

Example, before:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" 
 translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO"
 id="ABC-XY-123">
...
</view>
```

After:

```
<scrollView 
 clipsSubviews="YES" 
 multipleTouchEnabled="YES" 
 contentMode="scaleToFill" 
 alwaysBounceVertical="YES" 
 translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" 
 id="ABC-XY-123">
...
</scrollView>
```